# Centralizar uma Div entre duas outras, uma em cada extremo

Tags: css

Apesar da descontinuação do tag `<center>`, ela ainda resolveu este meu probleminha d eforma simples, porém gostaria de saber como resolve-lo apenas usando `css`.

A ideia é colocar dois botões (ou `div's`) em cada extremo,e no centro colocar dois botões, como na imagem seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando a tag `<center>`, fiz apenas o seguinte:

```
<div style="float: left">
    <p:commandButton  .../>
</div>
<center>
    <p:commandButton ..."/>
    <p:commandButton .../>
</center>
<div style="float: right">
    <p:commandButton .../>
</div>
```

**Nota:** A `div` que poderia colocar os dois botões centrais não tem um tamanho fixo, pode mudar dinamicamente, por isto, não utilizei o `margin: 0 auto`.

Como fazer isso usando `css`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há muitas maneiras de se chegar nesse resultado. Veja uma bem simples:

HTML

```
<div class="barra">
   <button class="l">&lt</button>
   <button>Confirmar</button>
   <button>Cancelar</button>
   <button class="r">&gt</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.barra {
   position: relative;
   padding:0 100px; /* ajuste conforme o tamanho dos botoes das pontas */
   text-align:center;
}

.barra .l {position:absolute;left: 0}
.barra .r {position:absolute;right: 0}
```

Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/jm8sr0bm/)**.

### Versão com *pseudo-seletores*:

É praticamente a mesma coisa, só removemos as classes `.l` e `.r`. Lembrando que `:first-child`  é CSS2, e o `:last-child` é CSS3.

HTML

```
<div class="barra">
   <button>&lt</button>
   <button>Confirmar</button>
   <button>Cancelar</button>
   <button>&gt</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.barra {
   position: relative;
   padding:0 100px; /* ajuste conforme o tamanho dos botoes das pontas */
   text-align:center;
}

.barra :first-child {position:absolute;left: 0}
.barra :last-child {position:absolute;right: 0}
```

Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/s5fk6zap/)**.

**Cuidado: `.barra :first-child` (com espaço) não é a mesma coisa que `.barra:first-child`.

Comment: Para o `position:absolute;` funcionar corretamente, o elemento pai deve ser posicionado pelo menos com `position:relative;`, mesmo assim +1

Comment: @Jader atualizei conforme a observação, grato.

Comment: Oba! Esta é a solução mais simples que vi até ao momento. @Bacco, muito obrigado mano. :D

Comment: Qual a necessidade do `overflow: hidden;` @Bacco?

Comment: @Cold até já tirei neste caso, acho que é força do hábito qu eu tenho, pra quando precisar enfiar um float no elemento ele nao escapar :). Mas procure lembrar que o overflow:hidden tem o efeito colateral de esticar a div pra englobar o conteúdo em algumas situações.

Answer (score 2):

Caso você não tenha restrições com browsers mais antigos, vale a pena utilizar o [Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) do CSS3:

```
.conteudo {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
.conteudo .meio {
    flex-grow:1;
    text-align:center;
}
.conteudo .dir, .conteudo .esq {
    flex-basis:50px;
}
```

E o HTML seria:

```
<div class="conteudo">
    <button class="esq"><-</button>
    <div class="meio"> <!-- Seu conteúdo aqui --> </div>
    <button class="dir"><-</button>
</div>
```

Exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/q9bdcy4d/)